# How to use xpath to search an element whose specific children rather than other children contain certain keywords?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I admit my question is wordy and may be ambiguous. So I put it in this example:

```
<freshvideos>
    <video>
        <id>
            <![CDATA[ 4f1a6a21egfw4227eaff33de8f571f95 ]]>
        </id>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[ New England Snowstorm - \"Low Gear\" ]]>
        </title>
        <ensub>
            <![CDATA[ I put it in low gear and take it slow. ]]>
        </ensub>
        <cnsub>
            <![CDATA[ 我挂了抵挡，慢慢开。 ]]>
        </cnsub>
        <filesrc>
            <![CDATA[ videos/New England Snowstorm Low Gear.mp4 ]]>
        </filesrc>
    </video>
    <video>
        <id>
            <![CDATA[ 5fgssd21e779d227eaff33de8f5gesfg ]]>
        </id>
        <title>
            <![CDATA[ New England Rain- \"High Gear\" ]]>
        </title>
        <ensub>
            <![CDATA[ I put it in high gear and take it quick. ]]>
        </ensub>
        <cnsub>
            <![CDATA[ 我挂了高挡，快快开。 ]]>
        </cnsub>
        <filesrc>
            <![CDATA[ videos/New England Rain High Gear.mp4 ]]>
        </filesrc>
    </video>
</freshvideos>
```

I want to pinpoint the id of one "video" by search for keywords in "title", "ensub", and "cnsub", but not in "filesrc".

Say, if I search "gear 慢慢"， which appear respectively in first video's "ensub" and "cnsub", it returns 1st "video".

Currently, I'm using

```
xpath "//video[contains(.,'gear') and contains(.,'慢慢')]".
```

Problem is I don't want to search other elements like "filesrc", because I worry about the performance of my php hosting server.

So I also tried xpath:

```
"video[title[contains(.,'gear') and contains(.,'慢慢')]|
ensub[contains(.,'gear') and contains(.,'慢慢')]|
cnsub[contains(.,'gear') and contains(.,'慢慢')]]"
```

New problem is, if I use "and" between the two contains()'s, no video element is matched. If I use "or" between them, all video elements are matched.

I also tried

```
"video[contains(tile|ensub|cnsub,'gear') and contains(tile|ensub|cnsub,'慢慢')]"
```

and it selected nothing. Do I miss something here in the xpath?

So is there an xpath expression that means "Match the 'video' element whose 'title','ensub', and 'cnsub' together contain 'gear' and '慢慢' "?

Thanks in advance!!
Hope I'm understood.

Comment: "I don't want to search other elements like "filesrc", because I worry about the performance of my php hosting server" How "complicate" you actual XML will be? You're already searching for 3 sub-elements (possibly with a complicate XPath), but are worried for including one more (with a simple XPath)?

Comment: Hi @Passerby! Do you mean my xml isn't complicate at all? I just have no clues whether my xpath is simple or not? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your XML is complicate at all. Immature "optimization" can be bad for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem myself.
I used

```
"video[contains(concat(title/text(),ensub/text()),'gear') and contains(concat(title/text(),ensub/text()),'慢慢')]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to match one of the elements in the set `(tile|ensub|cnsub)`:

```
"//video[ (tile|ensub|cnsub)[contains(.,'gear')] and
          (tile|ensub|cnsub)[contains(.,'慢慢')] ]"
```

If you only need to ensure that a child element of the `video` element contains both search terms:

```
"//video[ *[contains(.,'gear')] and *[contains(.,'慢慢')] ]"
```

I don't think you should rule out this second approach until you've tested it. I doubt it will make a substantial difference in the performance of your query.

**Update**

Removed XPath 2.0 function `string-join()` from the first code example.

Comment: Hi @joemfb! I'm interested in the first approach! I need to match all the three elements (title|ensub|cnsub). How can I get this from your first xpath approach? Thanks!!

Comment: the string-join() function doesn't work on my php: Warning: DOMXPath::query() [domxpath.query]: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function string-join not found in ... Is there a workaround?

Comment: My bad, `string-join()` is an XPath 2.0 function. I was just using it to avoid specifying the element set twice. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi @joemfb! I already got an answer for this. I use concat() instead, thanks to your inspiration! Thanks again!